# I ran out of votejuice, where's my Suffrage badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, voting-badges

This Sunday, I casted the maximum 40 votes in a day. That is, I got a message saying that I had exhausted my vote limit for the day. However, I don't have the Suffrage badge. Where did it go?

Comment: On which site? ...

Comment: Did you send the bribe money to the right place?

Comment: @Yannis Stack Overflow.

Comment: You already have the badge: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage?userid=1455016 - It's one of those that are only awarded once.

Comment: @Lance you mean Jon Skeet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As Yannis said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199126/i-ran-out-of-votejuice-wheres-my-suffrage-badge#comment632022_199126)...

> You already have the badge: [stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage?userid=1455016](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage?userid=1455016) - It's one of those that are only awarded once.

Comment: Hey, rare opportunity to upvote myself!

Comment: @Yannis And what have we learned? To post answers as answers! ;)

Comment: Meh, [a more interesting question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199127/162704) caught my eye. BTW didn't the badges page used to mention which badges are awarded only once and which multiple times?

Comment: @Yannis I don't think so. Or at least not consistently. I think that was just in that meta question that has longer descriptions of all of them.

Comment: I got so confused clicking that link and not seeing the page move at all. Scrolling to the perfect height on the page ftw!