# flagging option should link to definition of "site standards"

Tags: feature-request

An option for flagging questions is:

```
it should be closed for another reason...
  This question does not meet this site's standards and should be closed
```

It is somewhat unclear what "site standards" are being referred to. A hyperlink to some set of site standards would be helpful. This would prevent instances where a user [flags where they should have downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199127/163474)